# Direct implementation of $\exp (\boldsymbol{A} x)=e^{-\eta x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\boldsymbol{\eta} x)^{n}}{n !} \boldsymbol{P}^{n}$ in Python

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots n}$ be a squared matrix, $\eta = \max_i(-a_{ii}) > 0$, let $x \ge 0$ be a scalar, let $P$ be another squared matrix defined by $P=I+\eta^{-1}A$. I want to calculate matrix exponential of $A$, i.e. $exp(Ax)$, in  Python using/implementing $\exp (A x)=e^{-\eta x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\eta x)^{n}}{n !} P^{n}$ directly.

I will like to write a function which takes $A,x$ and $\epsilon$ as input, and give me the output of $\exp(Ax)$ within an error of $\varepsilon$.

Mathematically I can use that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\ell} \frac{(\eta x)^{n}}{n !} e^{-\eta x}>1-\varepsilon \implies 
\left\|\exp (A x)-e^{-\eta x} \sum_{n=0}^{\ell} \frac{(\eta x)^{n}}{n !} P^{n}\right\|<\varepsilon
$$

$||·||$ is just som matrix norm.

My **idea** was to make a while loop which calculates the $l$th partial sums of $e^{-\eta x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\eta x)^{n}}{n !} P^{n}$ until we have reached  the criteria $\sum_{n=0}^{\ell} \frac{(\eta x)^{n}}{n !} e^{-\eta x}>1-\varepsilon$. Then it should output $\exp(Ax)$.

For testing the following can be used:
$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-5 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & -6 & 4 \\
4 & 5 & -9
\end{array}\right), \: x =1 $
with the built-in function `expm` in `scipy.linalg`.

If the logic is  correct, can someone please help me with the coding part?

Comment: How is $\eta$ related to $A$ or $\|A\|$? Do you assume/ensure $\|P\|\le 1$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have written how $\eta$ is related to $A$ in my post, but it is defined as $\eta = \max_i(-a_{ii}) > 0$.
Yes, we  assume that $A$ is a sub-intensity matrix and $P$ is a sub-stochastic matrix. 

Regarding the matrix norm. It is the matrix norm induced by the maximum norm  on $\mathbb{R}$.  In my code I have not used this fact. 

I can post my code.

Comment: I rewrote this for incremental updates of the series terms, but did not change the logic. I get no such errors, setting `epsi=1e-4` results in the difference to the expm result to have entries smaller `2.5e-5` using 23 series terms.

Comment: The line `j=j+1` in the `summ` iteration is superfluous.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Alright. Thanks.

Comment: 29 terms and errors smaller `3.5e-8`, as requested from the method. Each row in the difference is essentially `[3.414488e-08 3.314061e-08 2.611079e-08]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see no egregious error in your code that would produce such numerical errors. To compare, I rearranged the code to avoid power computations in using the multiplicative increments of the series terms. With that implementation the difference to the `scipy.linalg.expm` result remains below the requested error treshold.

```
import scipy as scp

def expm_iteration(A,x,epsilon):    
    # checked
    eta = np.max(-np.diag(A))
    
    # checked exp(-eta·x)·I
    exp_eta_x = np.exp(-eta*x)

    n = 0 
    nth_partial_sum =  exp_eta_x * np.eye(A.shape[0])
    nth_term = exp_eta_x * np.eye(A.shape[0])
    scalar_exp_sum = exp_eta_x
    scalar_nth_term = exp_eta_x
    
    # Defining P.
    P = np.eye(A.shape[0]) + (1/eta) * A
    
    while True:
        n = n + 1
        nth_term = (eta*x / n) * nth_term.dot(P)
        scalar_nth_term = eta*x*scalar_nth_term / n
        nth_partial_sum = nth_partial_sum + nth_term
        scalar_exp_sum = scalar_exp_sum + scalar_nth_term
         
             
        if n>100 or 1 - scalar_exp_sum < epsilon:
            print(f"{n+1} terms")
            return nth_partial_sum

#----------------  main --------------

A = np.array([
                [-5, 2, 3],
                [2, -6, 4],
                [4, 5, -9]
])

x = 1
epsi = 1e-7

exp_xA = expm_iteration(A,x,epsi)
print(exp_xA)
print(scp.linalg.expm(x*A)-exp_xA)
```

with the output for this test case

```
29 terms
[[0.36595707 0.35453829 0.27950455]
 [0.36527458 0.35510046 0.27962487]
 [0.36551521 0.35489923 0.27958547]]
[[3.41448802e-08 3.31406189e-08 2.61107906e-08]
 [3.41448802e-08 3.31406189e-08 2.61107905e-08]
 [3.41448799e-08 3.31406189e-08 2.61107905e-08]]
```

Comment: Now I want to add another level of sophistication to the method. 

The problem with our method so far is that It does not work with large $x$. E.g. $x=1000$ and $\varepsilon = 1e-4$.

To make the code work for big $x$'s, one can use the method called scaling-and-squaring, where it is used that $\exp (A x)=[\exp (A x / m)]^{m},m=2^N$. 

$N$ must satisfy that it is the smallest with the following property $x/2^N\in[0,1]$. To find this $N$ I have written the following code.. please see my answer

Comment: Yes, that is always a problem with the exponential series. The terms of $\exp(x)$ are increasing until $n\sim |x|$ and rapidly decreasing after $n>2|x|$, where the value of the term reaches $e^{|x|}$. This is all very problematic numerically. // The question remains, can the result for $x=1000$ of $\exp(Ax)$ be represented at all in floating point?

Comment: For the answer to your last question: no because the computer do not have enough bits, right? I mean, then matrix one get for $x=1000$ and $exp(Ax)$ is very close to the zero matrix.

Comment: When adding scaling-and-scaring I get some of the entires in the matrix $\exp(Ax)$ to be around 4.000.000